# How do you document your Less?

Tags: css, less

I use JSDoc to document all the JS I write, but I am curious about how people document their less. I guess I could use JSDoc, but it doesn't seem right since less is not JS. I also want to avoid documenting my less with JSDoc if there is a standard way that might allow different IDEs to provide tooling support.

Does anyone know of a standard way of documenting less?

Comment: It's not a standard, but have you used Docco? From my experience, it's nice and simple for documenting arbitrary text files (such as CSS files).

Comment: I haven't heard of Docco before, but I will look into it!

Comment: Personally is should focus on generating style guides. Two tool which work well with Less code are [StyleDocco](http://jacobrask.github.io/styledocco/) and [Tdcss.js](http://jakobloekke.github.io/tdcss.js/) both tool requires that you add some (strictly) formatted comments to your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documenting source code involves different issues, and may have different objectives, than documenting CSS, be it LESS or any other variant.

Source code involves classes and methods involving contracts, such as the types and meaning of parameters and return values. It also may have complex logic that requires explanation, or handle multiple conditions, or deal with various edge cases. It may be implementing an API which third parties will consume, which should have its own stand-along documentation that can be "read". Systems such as JSDoc are designed with all this in mind. People reading the code can easily understand the purpose and signature and logic of the various routines, **and** the comments can be processed into API documents.

In a similar vein, source code is typically organized logically into a hierarchy of modules and classes. When reading the documentation, it's common to want to jump from a description of a subclass to the description of its superclass, or up to the module level. Tools like JSDoc also make this easy, by spitting out sets of interlinked HTML pages, most often.

On the other hand, consider a library such as Underscore, to which only some parts of the above apply. There are no modules, or classes, or class hierarchies. Instead, it is a bag of tools. Therefore, there is really no need for a lot of JSDoc-like machinery. Instead, what I want to do is to be able to READ the code and easily see what's happening, or get a narrative about the functions provided, probably with some code examples. That's why they use Docco, as recommended by a commenter. It's perfect for that. And as the commenter also mentioned, it can be used with almost any programming language, including CSS.

Compared to "languages" like JavaScript, CSS is (typically) flatter, and does not have the notion of "contracts" of parameters and return values, nor complex computations, although in systems like LESS of course you have mix-ins and calculations. With CSS, you also have the situation that in many cases the effect of the CSS is something visual, like say a button colored a certain way with text of a certain size. We have two potential consumers of comments in CSS: the programmer who is actually looking at the CSS code, and the UI designer or implementor who wants to know what styles are defined and check how they work.

Personally, I would adopt two approaches here, mapped to the two types of consumers. In the CSS code itself, I'd simply comment narratively, describing the purpose and structure of the rule. Parallel to that, I'd build a separate "styleguide" site, which contains visual examples of all the styles. There have been various attempts to automate the creation of such styleguides, with varying degrees of success. I have not used them, so cannot say how useful they might be. Personally, I'd go with a hand-rolled style guide.

It's also worth pointing out that the only thing worse than no documentation is wrong documentation. Whatever documentation approach you take, you have to make sure it's really sustainable and maintainable. In that sense, simpler is better.

Finally, let me note that the need for extensive documentation is inversely proportional to how well designed a set of styles and classes is. There is not much point in papering over baroque designs with poorly factored classes, weird dependencies, and poor naming, with lots of documentation. Instead, you might want to focus on refactoring your CSS so it's at least a bit more self-documenting.